# GWT CellBrowser with CompositeCell

Tags: gwt, uibinder, composite-controls, cellbrowser

I am trying to build a CellBrowser as given below.

```
Week 1 -> Mathematics
Week 2    [] Algebra
Week 3    [] Trigonometry
          Science
          [] Physics
          [] Chemistry
```

The problem is, I am not able to get the headings (*Mathematics* and *Science*) as given in the above code. The heading are from different Object, and my CompositeCell (CheckBox and TextCell) seems to be expecting/applying for all items.

Basically, I am trying to build the list in CellBrowser with some of them having (CheckBox and TextCell) while some of them having only (TextCell).

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the render method either of your `CompositeCell` or the `CheckBoxCell`. Something like this:

```
public class MyCompositeCell extends CompositeCell<Course>
{
    @Override
    protected <X> void render(Context ctx,Course value, 
                            SafeHtmlBuilder sb, HasCell<Course, X> hasCell) {
    if (hasCell.getCell() instanceof CheckBoxCell && !value.hasCheckBox())
        return;
    super.render(ctx,value, sb, hasCell);
}
```

The function `hasCheckBox()` is just an example. Either you access a flag in your DTO (`Course`) or you can pass a flag directly to the Cell.

Alternatively you can modify the render method of your CheckBoxCell:

```
public class MyCheckBoxCell extends CheckBoxCell<Course> {

    @Override
    public void render(Context ctx,Transformation value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (!value.hasCheckBox())
            return;
        super.render(ctx,value, sb);
    }
```